# Loop termination check for multiple types of host reachability tests

Tags: java, networking, event-handling

I have 2 booleans: `host.isReachableOnLan`, and `host.isReachableOnWan`

I have a listener `onItemClick` doing work on network on button event

Then I have an anonymous thread than runs a while loop, evaluating the booleans each iteration with the `evalFlag` method.

This works, but feels hackish and wrong. Is there a more elegant way of accomplishing the same goal? Hopefully one without my `evalFlag` method.

I would also like to combine the last two `if` statements at the top of my `onItemClick` method, because they feel redundant, but they're there for `evalFlag`.

```
Host host;

private boolean evalFlag(int type) {
    switch (type) {
    case 0:
        return !host.isReachableOnLan && !host.isReachableOnWan;
    case 1:
        return host.isReachableOnLan;
    case 2:
        return host.isReachableOnWan;
    }
    return false;

}

@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
    host = MainActivity.mainActivity.listAdapter.getItem(arg2);
    int tmp = -1;

    if (!host.isReachableOnLan && !host.isReachableOnWan) {
        new WakeOnLan(host, host.wolBroadcast).start();
        new WakeOnLan(host, host.wanHostName).start();
        tmp = 0;
    }

    else if (host.isReachableOnLan) { // want to combine this statement
        new ExecuteSshCommand(host, host.sshShutdownCommand).start();
        tmp = 1;
    }

    else if (host.isReachableOnWan) { // with this one
        new ExecuteSshCommand(host, host.sshShutdownCommand).start();
        tmp = 2;
    }

    final int type = tmp;
    new Thread() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            MainActivity.mainActivity.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(true);
            host.isLoading = true;

            MainActivity.mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.mainActivity.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });
            int timeSum = 0;
            HostCheck checker = new HostCheck(MainActivity.mainActivity, host, false);

            while (evalFlag(type) && timeSum < checker.loopTimeout) {
                final long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
                checker.run();
                if(host.isReachable())
                    try {
                        sleep(500);
                    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                timeSum += (int) (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime);
            }
            MainActivity.mainActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    MainActivity.mainActivity.listAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                }
            });

            MainActivity.mainActivity.swipeRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            host.isLoading = false;
        }
    }.start();
```

Comment: I thought about what I needed, and scrapped my ungodly `evalFlag` I then defined `host.isReachable()` to return `isReachableOnLan || isReachableOnWan`. I  cached a variable `boolean wasReachable = host.isReachable();`, and changed the loop to `while(((wasReachable && isReachable()) || (!wasReachable() && !isReachable())) && timeSum < checker.loopTimeout) {...}`. I've also cleened up everything else like you guys suggested.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Good names make everything better

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2, long arg3) {
```

This signature was clearly generated by a tool. Even though you only need one of the arguments and it is used on the first line of the function doesn't mean the arguments shouldn't have good names.

What happens if I need to use the `long` argument later? I haven't been in this code for a while, but I just have to add this one simple line. I'm pretty sure `arg2` was the `long`. Oops, `arg3` is the `long` and the `int` gets implicitly converted and the complier doesn't care. If the arguments had real names, it would be much harder to make this mistake.

That is some what of a contrived example because you could just look at the signature to see that `arg3` is the `long`. But how about this. I haven't had to implement an `OnItemClickListener` before. I don't know what the arguments are supposed to mean. Why is there a `long` and an `int`? Since you didn't take the time to give the arguments real names, I need to look at the documentation to see what each argument means.

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
```

Seeing that gives me a good idea of the context. Then only if I need more information do I have to look at the documentation.

---

`type` also doesn't help me know anything about what this variable is doing. Add the fact that it is an int and there tons of possible values, how do I know what the right value is and I use it properly?

```
enum HostConnectivity { Lan, Wan, Both }

// ...

final HostConnectivity connectionType = tmp;
```

Now it is clearer what kind of type we are dealing with and what each value means. This also removes the magic numbers from `evalFlag()`. It makes it easy to see if the `switch` does the wrong check for one of the cases.

Using `tmp` *can* be acceptable when it is a short lived variable that actually is temporary. (See the middle section to see how it can be removed and solve another problem.)

---

`evalFlag()` is a very generic name. It sounds like it is doing some operation on the `flag` variable. But there is no `flag` variable. Also, flags are generally throughout of as `boolean`, either set or not. Your type has multiple states.

What the method is doing is performing a check of the host's connectivity. it happens to be using the type to decide what checks to perform. The `while` loop isn't concerned with how the type is being used, it cares about what the `boolean` result. `checkHostConnetivity()` would be a much better name.

### Sub-functions make life easier

Extracting the type selection code into a sub-function.

```
private HostConnectivity chooseConnectivity() {
    if (!host.isReachableOnLan && !host.isReachableOnWan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Both;
    }
    else if (host.isReachableOnLan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Lan;
    }
    else {
        return HostConnectivity.Wan;
    }
}
```

Now there is no need for a temporary variable. Also, by separating the choosing from the initialization, you can remove the repeated code that you had a comment about wanting to combine.

```
final HostConnectivity connectionType = chooseConnectivity();
switch(connectionType) {
  case Both:
    new WakeOnLan(host, host.wolBroadcast).start();
    new WakeOnLan(host, host.wanHostName).start();
    break;
  case Wan:
  case Lan:
    new ExecuteSshCommand(host, host.sshShutdownCommand).start();
    break;
}
```

### Instances never die

There are a number of times when you create a new instance, never store the reference, and just start the operation. You should be careful with this. You need to make sure that these things can not run for ever. The `OnItemClickListener` might not be able to know if/when the thread should stop running. But it is very likely that you might want to kill the tread before it has completed. It is not clear what `WakeOnLan` and `ExecuteSshCommand` are doing and if they might also have a potential to run for a long time. Or maybe they fail and need to be checked later.

It is possible that not storing the references is not a problem in this case. But this type of action should be done with care.

Comment: I have cleaned up the top of my `onItemClick` with your enum suggestion. How would you suggest feeding the while loop the correct boolean value? A method with a switch statement that simply returns my booleans depending on the enum value?

Comment: ferada's answer talks about how to do this. The easy way would to be just replace the existing switch with the enum instead of the int. The `HostCheck` interface is another good idea as the switch will always resolve to the same case for a given execution.

Answer (score 3):

I think the better OOP choice here would be to introduce a separate
object to pass to the checker thread, i.e. `new HostCheck(host)` with a
`boolean check()` method.  You still have the choice of doing it just
via an interface, or by adding three new classes, I'd probably go with
anonymous classes if it's just an indirection.  With Java 8 you could
also pass member methods directly.

Even if you decide to keep it this way you still should definitely
replace the `int` with an enumeration instead.  `evalFlag` is also a
terrible name for what it does, how about
`isHostReachable(HostReachabilityType type)` or so, even if it would be
more verbose it's more describtive.
The two `ifs` could be merged with
`if (host.isReachableOnLan || host.isReachableOnWan)`; in the block
you'd to `tmp = host.isReachableOnLan ? 1 : 2`.  I doubt that's cleaner
though.  I'd prefer a method for `new ExecuteSshCommand...` and then
calling that twice like you do now.

Now you'll have to bear with me while I also comment on the rest of the
code.

- In general I'd say the code should be less nested.  Just extract
  everything into separate classes, then it's also testable (hint
  hint), most importantly the `Thread` subclass.
- Are the methods on `host` thread-safe?  Also, if `HostCheck` executes
  another thread you should probably wait on it instead of spawning more
  of them.
- The `printStackTrace` is arguably not very good, take a look at
  [this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3976344/handling-interruptedexception-in-java);
  I think if the thread was interrupted at that point you'd probably
  exit to the rest of the method instead, cleaning up the UI state.
- The blocks with `notifyDataSetChanged` are duplicated.  Put that into
  a separate method instead.
- It might also make sense to create a `try/catch` block around all of
  the thread to run the `setRefreshing(false)/host.isLoading = false` in
  a `finally` if an error occurs.
- I get that `arg0/1/2/3` are auto-generated, however since you're using
  `arg2` you should give it a better name.

Answer (score 1):

This code can be simplified:

```
private HostConnectivity chooseConnectivity() {
    if (!host.isReachableOnLan && !host.isReachableOnWan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Both;
    }
    else if (host.isReachableOnLan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Lan;
    }
    else {
        return HostConnectivity.Wan;
    }
}
```

To

```
private HostConnectivity chooseConnectivity() {
    if (!host.isReachableOnLan && !host.isReachableOnWan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Both;
    }
    if (host.isReachableOnLan) {
        return HostConnectivity.Lan;
    }
    return HostConnectivity.Wan;

}
```

But really, you should have something more like this:

```
public class Host {

private enum Connectivity{
 BOTH {
   public void attempt() {
    new WakeOnLan(host, host.wolBroadcast).start();
    new WakeOnLan(host, host.wanHostName).start();
   }
 }, 
 LAN{
   public void attempt() {
       new ExecuteSshCommand(host, host.sshShutdownCommand).start();
   }
 }, 
 WAN{
   public void attempt() {
       new ExecuteSshCommand(host, host.sshShutdownCommand).start();
   }
 }

   public abstract void attempt();
}



host.connect() {
  // this substitutes for your switch/case
  Connectivity.values()[connectType].attempt();     
}
}
```

This is rough code. But, it takes advantage of

- Enums are full-on classes and can have methods. That means, polymorphism.
- Enums are compiled with ordinals in the the order declared as is 'values()'. That means you have a 1-1 perfect hash mapping.

I don't know enough about android but in Swing, for example, a combo box took, in it's constructor an

```
Object[]
```

People generally took this to mean a String[] as that is what they saw in the dropdown. But ask yourself: Why Object[] then? Assume we transpos your case to Swing for a moment. You could pass in your Object[] into the constructor and override the toString() in your enums to display something useful as that is what would show up. Then when the selection is made you receive the callback telling you what it was (as an Object). But you know it's your enum. So, you downcast it and blindly call the 'attempt' method on it.

If you have something similar in your arsenal, consider it. What you have here, actually, is an example of the [Command Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Command_pattern)